# thread.sleep(5000); and TimerThread.sleep(5000); in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

What is difference between

`thread.sleep(5000);`

and

`TimerThread.sleep(5000);`

in java

Thanks

Comment: this question is easily answered using google search

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about this [`TimerThread`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/TimerThread.html), then there is no difference. The two ways to call `sleep()` resolve to the same method (`Thread.sleep()`).

I would expect this to be the case for any other reasonable class that extends `Thread`. However, if in doubt, one can always check the source code for the class in question.

Answer (score 0):

**TimerThread extends Thread**. So Thread.sleep(5000) and TimerThread.sleep(5000) is not different.

Comment: I am afraid the second sentence does not automatically follow from the first. It would be a pretty unreasonable thing to do, but `TimerThread` could provide its own `sleep()` method.

Comment: Also `sleep` is static so really the two methods have no relationship at all.